# input must be 4-dimensional[1,30,144,192,3], error in tensorflow training

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gif

I'm trying to train a gif dataset but am getting this error. 
It says the error is probably because of the ResizeBilinear

This is the code for the resize bilinear

```
input_height, input_width = hub.get_expected_image_size(module_spec)
input_depth = hub.get_num_image_channels(module_spec)
gif_data = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='DecodeGIFInput')
decoded_image = tf.image.decode_image(gif_data, channels=None, 
dtype=tf.uint8, name=None)
# Convert from full range of uint8 to range [0,1] of float32.
decoded_image_as_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(decoded_image,
                                                    tf.float32)
decoded_image_4d = tf.expand_dims(decoded_image_as_float, 0)
resize_shape = tf.stack([input_height, input_width])
resize_shape_as_int = tf.cast(resize_shape, dtype=tf.int32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(decoded_image_4d,
                                       resize_shape_as_int)
return gif_data, resized_image
```

This is the link to the github of the full file. 
[Link to github retrain.py](https://github.com/GauranshMathur/retrainpy/blob/master/retrain.py)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace with the error please.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the list in your title corresponds to `[?,batch_size,height,width,channels]`. If so, and assuming that you do not need the first dimension (`[1]`), you can replace

`resized_image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(decoded_image_4d,resize_shape_as_int)`

with

```
squeezed_image = tf.squeeze(decoded_image_4d,0)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(squeezed_image,resize_shape_as_int)
```

`tf.squeeze` will eliminate the first dimension (corresponding to axis `0`) and this should stop the error from popping up

Comment: Yeah i tried that and it gave this error, could not convert string to float: '[1.1535422  0.00437712 0.1985563  ... 0.24533136 0.06063589 0.20307699]'

Comment: That means your input is a `string`, not a number. You can use `tf.string_to_number` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_to_number) to solve this. But I have no clue on how it is getting converted to `string` in the first place.